# An Open Source Project Made With Nettiers

Tags: asp.net, open-source, .nettiers

Do you know any open source web application, which used nettiers as DAL inside the project?
I want to see that, how thay use it in their's project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [demo project](http://petshop.nettiers.com/) called pet shop. At bottom of page their is a view code link.

I think you can also download the app as a zip [from here](http://community.codesmithtools.com/forums/p/3084/12867.aspx)

It is not labelled as "Open Source" but it does show a working asp.net example

Comment: I need a project a bit bigger from it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate what it is you are after? This project contains all the features that you need CRUD etc. When you say bigger what do you mean?

Comment: Hello,

The PetShop application built by the .netTiers team is Open Source and can be used freely.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski